# integral of product of sin and cos

Tags: integration

$$\int \sin 3x \cos 2x\ dx$$

Any help with this question?
Can't seem to get around it with integration by parts or u-substitution. Was trying to get it to repeat and solve from a single side. many thank!

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee But the real name of [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) is few mentioned in scholar maths, so does the [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html).

Answer (score 3):

Note that:
$$\color{blue}{\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\frac 1 2 (\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\sin(\alpha+\beta))}$$

S0

$$\frac 1 2 \int (\sin(5x)+\sin(x))dx=\frac 1 2 \int \sin(5x)dx+\frac 1 2\int\sin(x)dx=-\frac{\cos x}{2}-\frac{\cos (5x)}{10}+\mathcal C$$

Answer (score 2):

By parts,

$$I=\int \sin(3x)\cos(2x)dx=-\frac13\cos(3x)\cos(2x)+\frac23\int\cos(3x)\sin(2x)dx.$$

By parts once again,

$$I=-\frac13\cos(3x)\cos(2x)+\frac29\sin(3x)\sin(2x)-\frac49\int\sin(3x)\cos(2x)dx\\
=-\frac13\cos(3x)\cos(2x)+\frac29\sin(3x)\sin(2x)-\frac49I.$$

This gives you the value of $I$ !

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \sin 3x\cos 2x\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\int(2\sin 3x\cos 2x) \ dx$$
$$=\frac 12\int (\sin(3x+2x)+\sin(3x-2x))\ dx$$
$$=\frac 12\int (\sin(5x)+\sin(x))\ dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\cos 5x}{5}-\cos x\right)+C$$